# Jsoup (basic .class) CSS selectors not working - html() shows elements exist, and less specific selector works

Tags: java, css, web-scraping, css-selectors, jsoup

**Sorry, this is kind of a long post. If you scroll down to the bottom edit, the problem will probably be clear.**

A portion of the page I'm parsing:

```
<a href="/MangaList/MostPopular">Sort by popularity</a>
<a href="/MangaList/Newest">New manga</a>
<a class="bigChar" href="/Manga/Shinryaku-Ika-Musume">Shinryaku! Ika Musume</a>
<a href="/Genre/Comedy" class="dotUnder" title="A dramatic work that is light and often humorous or satirical in tone  and that usually contains a happy resolution of the thematic conflict.">Comedy</a>
```

I specifically want to pull the 3rd `<a>` tag with class "bigChar". It's the only occurrence of the "bigChar" class on the page. This should be straightforward enough. I do the same thing on a page from another site, and it works totally fine.

```
  Document doc = MCache.getDocument(url);
    if (doc == null)
        return null;
    Series series = new Series();
    series.source = this.getSourceName();
    series.imageURL = getImageURL(doc);
    M.debug("selecting from " + doc.html() + " " + doc.select(".bigChar") + " with a " + doc.select("a") + " final " +  doc.select("a.bigChar"));
    series.title = doc.select(".bigChar").first().ownText();
```

Above is the segment of code I'm running.

For some reason, doc.select(".bigChar") is not getting anything, so doc.select(".bigChar") is throwing a NPE.

You can see my debug output line in the code above. Here is what it outputs:

```
selecting from <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <title>
...<div> 
      <a class="bigChar" href="/Manga/Shinryaku-Ika-Musume">Shinryaku! Ika Musume</a> 
      <p> <span class="info">Genres:</span>&nbsp;<a href="/Genre/Comedy" class="dotUnder" title="A dramatic work that is light and often humorous or satirical in tone  and that usually 
....
 with a <a href="http://kissmanga.com/Login">Login</a>
<a href="http://kissmanga.com/Register"> Register</a>
...
<a class="bigChar" href="/Manga/Shinryaku-Ika-Musume">Shinryaku! Ika Musume</a>
...
  final
```

To be clear: in the "selecting from" part, I output the `document.html()`. This includes the desired `<a>` tag with the bigChar class.

The "with a" part, I print the results of `document.select("a")`. These results include the `<a>` tag with the bigChar class.

At the end, I print "final" followed by `document.select(".bigChar")`. For whatever reason, this doesn't select anything. I've also tried `a.bigChar` as the selector. Calling `.first()` on the Elements returned by both of those selectors gives null, since it doesn't seem to select anything.

Does anyone know what's going on here? I know selectors can be tricky but I'm pretty sure I'm not making a mistake considering it's just selecting a single class... I'm especially confused by why the `a` selector includes the tag I want, even showing the same class, but `.bigChar` doesn't select it.

**Edit: I tried adding some more debugging code:**

```
    Elements as = doc.select("a");
    for (Element e : as) {
        if (e.classNames().size() > 0)
            M.debug(e.classNames());
        if(e.classNames().contains("bigChar")) {
            M.debug("found!");
        }
    }
    as = doc.select(".bigChar");
    M.debug("now: " + as);
    for (Element e : as) {
        if (e.classNames().size() > 0)
            M.debug(e.classNames());
    }
```

The output:

```
[logo]
[bigChar]
found!
[dotUnder]
[dotUnder]
[dotUnder]
[dotUnder]
[dotUnder]
now:
```

So the bigChar is even seen as a class, but the .bigChar selector is not getting it...

Comment: Can you create an example of the failure with a minimal static html, so that we maybe can reproduce this? Because in my tests of this, all was working as expected

Comment: I'm on my phone right now so I can't edit this easily, but I opened an issue and attached a sample file there (blahblah.txt) https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/issues/830